# Unity 4.6 AutoConvert fbx file to Prefab file bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i try many times, but failed, so i think maybe this is unity 4.6's bug;

Unity 4.6
Windows 7 64bit

Requirement:when i import the fbx file, auto generate prefab file.

step1 :
1 in OnPostprocessModel （Editor folder）
2 below 4 method all return null:

```
   string path3 = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test\Assets\Resources\Models\Item.fbx";
   object obj1 = AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath(path3);
   object obj2 = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path3, typeof(GameObject));

   object obj3 = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(path3, typeof(GameObject));
   object obj4 = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(path3);
```

Comment: Why do you need to auto convert? Why don't you make the prefab first and use it?

Comment: because i have many fbx file to convert prefab, and need add component. i want to write a tool to do this step, save my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug, you are just never finding your object. Because you are providing the wrong path.

all 4 functions you are running require your model to either be inside the Resources folder or the Assets folder. So you will want to use path names as following

```
Assets/Resources/Models/Item.fbx
Resources/Models/Item.fbx
```

also the [unity wiki](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) teaches us the following

```
Note:
All asset names & paths in Unity use forward slashes, 
paths using backslashes will not work.
```

Beside's that I don't think you should be using these functions, but you should be using the [PrefabUtility](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab.html) instead. A good sample of this can be found on [unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/27626/how-to-create-prefabs-from-editor-scripts.html)

```
 // Create some asset folders.
AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets/Meshes", "MyMeshes");
AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets/Prefabs", "MyPrefabs");

// The paths to the mesh/prefab assets.
string meshPath = "Assets/Meshes/MyMeshes/MyMesh01.mesh";
string prefabPath = "Assets/Prefabs/MyPrefabs/MyPrefab01.prefab";
// Delete the assets if they already exist.
AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset(meshPath);
AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset(prefabPath);

// Create the mesh somehow.
Mesh mesh = GetMyMesh();

// Save the mesh as an asset.
AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(mesh, meshPath);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
// Create a transform somehow, using the mesh that was previously saved.
Transform trans = GetMyTransform(mesh);
// Save the transform's GameObject as a prefab asset.
PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(prefabPath, trans.gameObject);
```